# Using ng-options to show object property but bind index with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to display a list of the names of the teams in a league, and select one. When selected, it should place the index of `league.teams[index]` into `homeTeam.teamId`. Here is the HTML:

```
<select
    ng-model="homeTeam.teamId"
    ng-options="team.name for team in league.teams">
</select>
```

And here the scope:

```
$scope.league = {
    teams: [
        { name: "Team#1" },
        { name: "Team#2" }
    ]
};
```

But it adds the whole object into `homeTeam.teamId`, like this:

```
homeTeam: {
    "teamId": { "name":"Team#1" }
}
```

How can I get it to just input the index, i.e.:

```
homeTeam: {
    "teamId": 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an id then the teams should have one:

`ng-options="team.id as team.name for team in league.teams"`

Alternative:

`ng-options="league.teams.indexOf(team) as team.name for team in league.teams"`

`indexOf()` is not supported by IE < 9

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with the first option and added ids. Seems like a more sensible route.